# How to reset Software Updater

Tags: upgrade

So I am running Groovy Gorilla here (20.10).
Yesterday Software Updater offered me the option to upgrade to Hirsute Hippo (21.04). I declined at that time. I thought I picked 'Not now".
I cannot remember which option I did pick, but now I don't see any option to upgrade at all.
I am reluctant to go through a fresh install, although I have done so previously.
Thanks. - Erny

Comment: You can always call the release upgrade with `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

This  reference suggests that it is now available to upgrade from v20.10 to 21.04 from May 11th 2021.

It includes the methods to employ in order to perform the upgrade.

[reference](https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-upgrade-ubuntu-20-10-to-ubuntu-21-04-heres-how)

In terminal `update-manager -c`will inform you how you can take the appropriate action.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I just tried that. It gave me that same notice, but _without_ the "Upgrade ..." button.

Comment: I just tried "sudo do-release-upgrade". He replied "No new release found."

Comment: These suggestions did not help. Does anyone else have any thing else?